# Inner sequential loop in outer parallel loop - OMP

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I have to parallelize the first for loop in OMP but inside it there is a for loop that is not parallelizable because of data dependencies. I tried with  parallel for in the outer for but there are problems with the pointers.

A minimal example of the problem:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main()
{

 int N = 5;
 int size = 6;
 int n, j, i;

 double t[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};


 double z, h2M, R2M, dz;
 int *dynamic_d;
 int *dynamic_A;
 int *dynamic_B;
 int *output;

 dynamic_d = (int *) calloc (N+1, sizeof(int));

 for(i = 0; i < N+1; i++){
    *(dynamic_d + i) = i;
 }

 dynamic_A = (int*) calloc (N+2, sizeof(int));
 dynamic_B = (int*) calloc (N+2, sizeof(int));
 output = (int*) calloc (size, sizeof(int));


 for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {  
    z = t[j] + 1;
    *dynamic_A = 0;
    *dynamic_B = 1;                   

    *(dynamic_A + 1) = *dynamic_d;
    *(dynamic_B + 1) = 1;

    for (n = 2; n <= N+1; n++) {
          dz = *(dynamic_d + n-1)*z;
          *(dynamic_A + n) = *(dynamic_A + n-1) + dz + (*(dynamic_A + n-2));
          *(dynamic_B + n) = *(dynamic_B + n-1) + dz + (*(dynamic_B + n-2));
    }

    h2M = z + *(dynamic_d + N-1) - *(dynamic_d + N);
    R2M = -h2M + z + *(dynamic_d + N);

    *(dynamic_A + N+1) = *(dynamic_A + N) + R2M + *(dynamic_A + N-1);
    *(dynamic_B + N+1) = *(dynamic_B + N) + R2M + *(dynamic_B + N-1);

    *(output + j) = t[j] + *(dynamic_A + N+1) + *(dynamic_B + N+1);
 }

 printf("\n\noutput:\n");
 for (j = 0; j < size; j++){
    printf("| %d ", output[j]);
 }
 printf("\n");

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve], that would make it much easier to provide a comprehensive answer. Also how did you use parallel,  and how exactly did it not work?

Answer (score 0):

The only data dependence is on the two arrays `dynamic_A` and `dynamic_B` since they are the only one that gets written and read in the loop. `dynamic_d` is only read and `output` gets only written to (so no problems there).

However, if you look closely to the `dynamic_A` and `dynamic_B` dependencies you can see that they are not loop-carried since any value of `dynamic_A[i]` computed in iteration `j` is only used within that iteration. The entire array will be overwritten in the next iteration of the outer-most loop.

You need to rewrite the code so that each thread has its own private copy of `dynamic_A` and `dynamic_B`. For example:

```
#pragma omp parallel private(dynamic_A, dynamic_B, z, h2M, R2M)
{
  dynamic_A = (int*) calloc (N+2, sizeof(int));
  dynamic_B = (int*) calloc (N+2, sizeof(int));

  #pragma omp for
  for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    ...
  }

  free(dynamic_A);
  free(dynamic_B);
}
```

Comment: This will fail if `dynamic_A` is a pointer (which seems likely given the name), a private pointer will just be initialized with `NULL`. That's why it's impossible to properly answer the question without an [mcve]...

Comment: Indeed, but the idea is that those arrays needs to be made thread-private.